# How to synchronize the filling of a ring buffer in a background thread with a remoteio callback

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-audio

Im looking for an implemtation that uses a ring buffer in remoteio to output a very large audio file.

I have come across the CARingBuffer from apple but I've had a nightmare trying to implement it in my ios project.

As an alternative I came across this ring buffer that I've using (unsuccessfully).

[Ring Buffer](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-simple-fast-circular-buffer-implementation-for-audio-processing/)

How I tried to implement this is as follows.

1. Open an audio file which is perfectly cut using extaudiofileref.
2. Fully fill my ring buffer reading from the file (number of frame % inTimeSamples = readpoint)
3. In my callback if the ring buffer is less than 50% full I call performselector in background to add more samples.
4. If there is enough samples I just read from the buffer.

This all seems to work fine until I come close to the end of the file and want to loop it. When the reapoint + the number of samples needed to fill the ring buffer exceeds the total number of frames I extract some audio from the remainder of the file, seek to frame 0, then read the rest.

This always sounds glitchy. I think it may have something to do with the fact that the remoteio callback is running much quicker than the background thread so by the time the background thread has completed not only has the calculated readpoint changed but the head and tail of the buffer are not what they should be.

If example code would be too immense to post I would accept pseudo code as an answer. My methodology to solve this is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but [SFBAudioEngine](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine) compiles and runs on iOS and will handle this use case easily.  It's basically a higher-level abstraction for the RemoteIO AU and supports many more formats than Core Audio does natively.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll take a look at the code later & see if I can make sense of it. At a very high level do you think my approach is suitable for what I'm attempting to achieve. If it does sound like a reasonable approach I may spend a little more time tinkering with my implmentation.

Comment: Your approach sounds reasonable to me.  It's very important to keep the ring buffer full, so I would run a background thread that does nothing except read audio from your file and store it in the ring buffer.

Comment: I've admitted defeat and decided to look at your project. I get errors trying to run the IOS simple Player Though. FLAC/metdata.h not found and FLAC/stream_decoder.h not found. Any Ideas.

Comment: You'll need to download the precompiled libraries and headers from github and save them to /opt to get the iOS version to compile.